# Including part of a php file?

Tags: php, file, include

I have an individual file for each page on my site, which contains a "page-specific head code" section and a "body" section. I have a master file that contains a "global head code" section, the page header (logo and navbar) and the page footer.

I'd like the master file to include the page file, but I can't just include the whole file because it would put my sections out of their proper order. Therefore, right now I define functions in my page files, and then call these functions at the proper points in my master file.

This approach works, but there are quite a few negatives associated with it:

- I can't edit the page files in Dreamweaver design view
- The page files are quite difficult to read
- There is redundant code, which I was trying to eliminate in the first place.

Is there a different, better way that I could do this? My goal is to have the page files be as simple as possible, and have all the complicated stuff happen in the master file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of suggestions:

- Break the HTML sections into different files, then include those file at the points where you need them.
- Wrap the sections of the 'page' file in functions, then call the functions from the master file. This way you don't have to duplicate code, you can just change the functions in the 'page' file.

Comment: While this was at one point a 'good' way of doing things, using object-oriented code and HTML templates is a more common practice now.

Comment: @zach Sorry if I wasn't clear with my explanation, but this is what I already do. The problem is that I have to put the same function definition in *every* single page file, and it makes the code look quite messy. I'd like the PHP to simply recognize something such as a simple HTML comment, and start the include process there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a templating engine such as smarty that lets you create/inherit/extend html files.  This would allow you to easily use things like headers and footers and other shared divs.

http://www.smarty.net/